# Which entity table should be used for data common to all revisions?

Tags: entities, 8

Translatable and revisionable entity has ho have four tables in Drupal 8: entity, entity_revision, entity_field_data and entity_field_revision.

Let's say I have a "product" entity and the product has a manufacturer. The manufacturer will be the same all the time, no matter which revision is active. Another example would be a "car" entity. The car will always have a certain ammount of wheels(4).

Where(in which table) should I put this "global" fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entity can have up to 4 tables, it doesn't have to. So if you don't need revisions or translations, you can simply not define them. There are 4 test entities in the entity_test.module that test every possible combination, only base table, base + revision, base + data/translation and all of them. So that should work fine.

other than that, it's fairly straight forward. The base table contains information that's the same for all revisions and all translations. _revision contains information that is for a specific revision but all translations. field_data and field_revision contain both the per-revision-per-translation, field_data being the data of the default revision, field_revision the same information for all revisions.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if {entity} is more suited for that or {entity_revision} since it only maps active revision to entity. But now I see that it was quite obviouse :)